# SimpleParserException: Unknown function: property.fileName

Tags: apache-camel, camel-sql

I'm using Apache Camel 3.0 and I'm getting this error when parsing the file:

```
    from("file:" + filePath)
            .routeId("create-ticket")
            .unmarshal(ticketCsv)
            .to("jpa:Ticket")
            .log("Created new ticket with id ${body.id}")
            .convertBodyTo(String.class)
            .setProperty("fileName", simple("${header.CamelFileAbsolutePath}"))
            .setProperty("fileContents", body())
            .to("sql:INSERT INTO DOCUMENT(document_name, document_contents) VALUES(:#${property.fileName}, :#${property.fileContents})");
```

Exception:

> org.apache.camel.language.simple.types.SimpleIllegalSyntaxException:
>   Unknown function: property.fileName at location 0 ${property.fileName}

Answer (score 8):

`${property.xxx}` is deprecated in 2.x. Use `${exchangeProperty.xxx}` which is the correct name for the function.

More changes can be found [in the migration guide](https://camel.apache.org/manual/latest/camel-3-migration-guide.html#_languages)